# what does спалила mean in this sentence?

Tags: сленг

excerpt from a song:

*"Ты **спалила** наверняка как он смотрит издалека".*

the direct translation of **спалила** or **спали́ть** is "to burn", however it does not make sense in this sentence.
According to https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C#Russian, **спали́ть** as a slang means "to catch someone doing something illegal or disallowed".

so should the sentence be translated to?

*"you caught how he looked from afar"*

Thanks!

Comment: this is a primitive slang. Well, in this contex :  "You founded out, you disclose, you seen..." The metaphorical idea is like as in some game -"if you was "founded out", you are "burned"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Since the song is a rap about a guy approaching a girl, the slang meaning fits in nicely:

- You surely saw him checking you out from a distance

Here is the context:

```
Эй
На тебе бандана — ты будто дочь Тупака
На типе панама — он будто сын рыбака
Ты спалила наверняка, как он смотрит издалека
У типа для тебя бокал, у тебя для типа "пока"
А я подойду, скажу, что не знаю с чего начать
Вроде нужно говорить, но можем и помолчать
Не дам тебе заскучать, возьму тебя рассмешу
Все вокруг будут нам мешать, все вокруг это просто шум
```

There is also the reflexive **спалиться** 'to get busted'.

Comment: Yeah that was the song I was looking at. The translation "You surely saw him checking you out from a distance" makes so much more sense now that you also mention "to get busted".  the other thing I missed is "он смотрит" actually has has a receipt of the "look" action. very helpful, thanks!